# Flat space Solution of Einstein Field Equation

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace

Does a trace-free energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu}^{\mu} = 0$ ensure that the Einstein's field equations have a flat space solution?

Comment: No, the solution need not be flat. Even if the tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ is zero, the solution will be Ricci flat, but the Rieman tensor can be non-zero.

Comment: It only means you get a zero Ricci curvature, i.e., $R=g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}=0$ for $d\neq2$, where $d$ is a spacetime dimension. For $d=2$ case, you have always trace-free energy-momentum tensor as you can easily check.

Comment: @Minkyu: You mean scalar curvature.

Comment: @MBN Yes. I was little confused, because there are many name of that. Actually, I usually call it a Ricci scalar.

Comment: And if the stress energy tensor is nonzero, then it is *guaranteed* that the geometry is *not* flat - because Einstein's equations say that the Ricci tensor is nonzero, too (and the Riemann tensor is therefore also nonzero). The vanishing of the trace of the stress energy tensor is far from enough for flatness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Einstein field equations
$$
R_{\mu\nu}~-~\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}~=~8\pi GT_{\mu\nu}
$$
for zero stress energy means that the Ricci Curvature $R_{\mu\nu}$ is proportional to the metric with $R_{\mu\nu}~=~\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}$. This is called an Einstein spacetime, and for a constant Ricci scalar $R~=~R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$ this is a spacetime of constant curvature, such as a 4-sphere.

By taking the trace of this Stress energy it is not hard to show that
$$
8\pi G\left(T_{\mu\nu}~-~\frac{1}{2}Tg_{\mu\nu}\right)~=~R_{\mu\nu}.
$$
The traceless condition $T~=~0$ just means the Ricci tensor is propotional to the stress energy, but the Ricci scalar is zero.

Comment: A spacetime of constant curvature would be a 3-sphere, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily see this isn't the case by considering the special case of the stress-energy tensor equal to zero i.e. the [vacuum solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity)). These include the Minkowski metric, which is flat, but also the Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics and of course gravitational waves.